# Storing treecache cluster properties in property file

Tags: java, spring, jboss, jboss-cache

I'm using Jboss 4, hibenate, spring and treecache. As we have different environments, I would like to store the cluster information in a separated property file and reference to the content from the treecache xml file. I copied the `treecache-optimistic.xml` into

```
\jboss-4.2.0.GA\server\Pearl\conf
```

and setup the properties in `\jboss-4.2.0.GA\server\Pearl\deploy\properties-service.xml`

```
 <attribute name="Properties">
    cluster.name=CluterName
 cluster.ip=228.1.3.1
 cluster.port=48866
    </attribute>
```

I tried to reference it in the treecache-optimistic.xml like this:

```
 <attribute name="ClusterName">${cluster.name}</attribute>
```

After starting the instance I found via JMX that the name of the cluster is `${cluster.name}` and not the value of the property (`ClusterName`). I thought that it can not find the property somehow, but if I change the reference to

```
<attribute name="ClusterName">${cluster.name:DefaultValue}</attribute>
```

then I get the following error:

> Exception starting filter `ServletRequestScopeFilter`
>   `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException`: Error creating bean with name '`pearlSessionFactory`' defined in class path resource [`hibernate-spring.xml`]: Invocation of `init` method failed; nested exception is `org.hibernate.cache.CacheException`: `javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException`: Invalid character ':' in value part of property

The hibernate properties are configured by spring:

```
 <!-- Database Property -->
    <bean id="hibernatePropertiesPearl"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="properties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.TreeCacheProvider</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">0</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">0</prop>
```

I do not know why the `treecache-optimistic.xml` can not handle property files :-(

Thanks
Zoltan